# Site Column,Site Content Type,List Content Type issue in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, content-type, site-column

In my Site Collection, I am facing a strange issue. I have custom Site Content Types, Site Columns created and these Site Columns were associated with Site Content Types.

After creation of Document Libraries I have associated with these Site Content Types with my Document Libraries through PowerShell.

But after completion of this association I am  unable to see few columns in the List Content Types. Is there any way I can get those Site Columns available in List Content Types either through PowerShell or Object Model?

Comment: Can you be more specific like what columns you are not seeing? Can you see those in browser?

Comment: Its available in site settings-->site columns level and I am able to see these columns as a part of the site content types also.But when it comes to the list content types,document library settings->content types section and when I expand the list content type I am not able to see those site columns.

Comment: Can You tell, how can I see those in browser?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot.. it seems you have not added those site columns to your list content type

Comment: I think I am facing the issue described [here](https://soerennielsen.wordpress.com/2007/09/11/propagate-site-content-types-to-list-content-types/)